# Grid of images like Facebook for Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-gridview, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I'd like to make a gallery images for android like Facebook application as below images but I can not find any guidle for this problem.
I think it's the grid view for images but size of images is different and the number of row for a column and number of column in a row maybe is different also.
Is there any library I can use or I have to custom the grid view for it.
Please give me a suggestion.

Thank in advanced!

[image: list of image in new feed]

[image: in gallery]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go,Perfect library for your requirement. [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView)

Comment: @PhanDinhThai Have you got this result?